# Javascript RegEx replace all characters not within HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Looking for a bit of help, my regex is a bit rusty...

I'm trying to replace all characters not within HTML tags in javascript by a character.

For example replace those characters by a dash "-",

```
<div class="test">Lorem Ipsum <br/> Dolor Sit Amet</div>
```

Would be replaced by:

```
<div class="test">------------<br/>--------------</div>
```

So I'm looking for

```
str.replace(/YourMagicalRegEx/g, '-');
```

Please help, I get how to return text not within html tags with regex, text within html tags with regex, but all characters not within html tags seems quite tricky...!

Additional Challenge: Must be IE7 and up compatible.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible (at least not that I am aware of) since it would require a lookbehind, which is not supported in JavaScript to my knowledge.  Workaround is to introduce jQuery 1.*, loop through all of the DOM elements you want, and then just apply simple [A-Z] and \s replacements.

Comment: I didn't read thoroughly the question :/ my answer was off.

Comment: There are [plenty of good reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/362634) not to try to solve this problem with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
html = '<div class="test">Lorem Ipsum <br/> Dolor Sit Amet</div>';
node = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
node.find('*').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = Array(this.nodeValue.length).join('-')

});
console.log(node.html())
```

(I don't have IE7 at hand, let me know if this works).

If you prefer regular expressions, it goes like this:

```
html = html.replace(/<[^<>]+>|./g, function($0) {
    return $0[0] == '<' ? $0 : '-';
});
```

Basically, we replace tags with themselves and out-of-tags characters with dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex-only approach, you can find all text nodes within the document and replace their content with hyphens.

Using the [**TreeWalker API:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)

```
 var tree = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

 while (tree.nextNode()) {
     var textNode = tree.currentNode;
     textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/./g, '-');
 }
```

A recursive solution:

```
function findTextNodes(node, fn){
  for (node = node.firstChild; node;node=node.nextSibling){
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) fn(node);
    else if(node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') findTextNodes(node, fn);
  }
}


findTextNodes(document.body, function (node) {
  node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/./g, '-');
});
```

The predicate `node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT'` is required to prevent the function from replacing any script content within the body.

Comment: Hm, I appreciate the alternative, but TreeWalkerAPI seems to be for IE9 and up, I should've mentioned this must be IE7 and up compatible... (I know, urh, IE)

Comment: Recursive solution still not IE7 compliant :(